# JQuery Time Picker basic example

Tags: timepicker

I am trying to implement the basic time picker in JQuery
but its not working at all

Please Help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="../js/jquery/themes/base/jquery.ui.timepicker.css"   

rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/ui/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id1').timepicker();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
Input: <input id="id1" type="text" name="fullname"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to place the jquery script tag before the timepicker script tag

Answer (score 0):

put this -->

```
$('input[name="TOH"]').ptTimeSelect();
```

instead of this-->

```
$('#id1').timepicker();
```

// dont write the id. just write the name of your html tag used.

and it will work like a miracle. i tried. and make sure your css and js files from your laptop has the proper file path.